# Alt-tab behavior

Tags: unity, 12.04

Couple of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> issues (Ubuntu 12.04):

Currently <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only switches between windows in the current workplace. How do I expend it to all ?

The icons when switching are tiny. Any way to make them bigger ?

Answer (score 2):

you can not just configure it in your way for you can see the bug here.
 applications on current focused windows are present in the <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> function not all windows
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/959339